# Are there any valid/working usages of MSForms.Control.RowSourceType property?

Tags: vba, properties, controls

An `MSForms.Control` has a property defined as `Property RowSourceType As Integer`, but any attempt to read or write the property seems to fail with error:

> Run-time error '-2147352573 (80020003)':
>
> Member not found.

Are there (or were there once) any built-in MSForms controls or ActiveX controls for which this property doesn't throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

A quick web search for VBA RowSourceType turns up a bunch of results for VBA Access. I've only dipped my toe into VBA for Access, and that was many years ago, so I can't say how it's used in Access. But I'm guessing that you're using VBA with something else (Excel, Word, etc.). I suspect the generic Control object is used across all application hosts.

Comment: Yes, the `RowSourceType` property in Access is specifically for the `Access.Listbox`, `Access.ComboBox` and `Access.ObjectFrame` classes, and is actually a `String` property in Access. It may well be a wrapper around the `MSForms.Control` property, but that isn't necessarily the case (and in any case, the String/Integer difference is obfuscated). It's the `MSForms.Control` that I'm interested in, or any `MSForms` control that implements the `IControl` interface's `RowSourceType` property.